# 'Question' object has no attribute 'choice_set' django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

i tried the django polls app but got this , my models included foreign key but i don't get it where's the problem

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('published date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

and here is the view:

```
def vote(request , primary_key):
question = get_object_or_404(models.Question, id=primary_key)
try:
    selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(id=request.POST['choice'])
except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
    return render(request,'polls/detail.html',{
        'question' : question ,
        'error_message' : "u didn't select a choice."
    })
else:
    selected_choice.vote += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args = (question.id)))
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'^$', views.index , name = 'index'),
re_path(r'^(?P<primary_key>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail, name = 'detail'),
re_path(r'^(?P<primary_key>[0-9]+)/results/$' , views.results , name = 'results'),
re_path(r'^(?P<primary_key>[0-9]+)/vote/$' , views.vote , name = 'vote'),
```

]

Comment: Can you provide full error traceback?

Comment: Can you also provide imports made on `views.py`

Answer (score 0):

have you made migrations and migrated them after defining your Choice class ?